# what are the difference between particle.publish event and particle.subscribe event in particle.cloud?

Tags: api, cloud, iot

what exactly does particle.publish and particle.subscribe event do in particle.cloud api .I was sort of confused over their application while building android application for internet of thing product.

Comment: i don't think it should be rated -1

Answer (score 0):

```
Particle.publish()
```

Publish an event through the Particle Cloud that will be forwarded to all registered callbacks, subscribed streams of Server-Sent Events, and other devices listening via Particle.subscribe().This feature allows the device to generate an event based on a condition. For example, you could connect a motion sensor to the device and have the device generate an event whenever motion is detected.

```
Particle.subscribe()
```

Subscribe to events published by devices.This allows devices to talk to each other very easily. For example, one device could publish events when a motion sensor is triggered and another could subscribe to these events and respond by sounding an alarm.

To use Particle.subscribe(), define a handler function and register it in setup().

References:

https://docs.particle.io/reference/firmware/photon/#cloud-functions